# Servo Torque Calculator

Tags: servo, torque

Does anyone have an easy to use Servo Torque Calculator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link I previously had here has long since died so here is a new one:

http://www.mnbigbirds.com/Servo%20Torque%20Caculator.htm

Which may or may not fit the bill.

Comment: Yep that's perfect!

I also found this one which has a nice bit of explanation of what it all means  :) 

http://www.workhouse.dk/br/sobre/about-me/servo-size-calculator/

Comment: There's some explanation here too (I think it may be the same) http://www.csd.net/~cgadd/eflight/calcs_servo.htm . What is Servo Torque anyway, something to do with flaps on Radio Controlled aircraft?

Comment: Bunch of dead links.